# How to add count to content with fs

Tags: javascript, npm, discord, discord.js, fs

I'm coding a `Discord Bot` at `discord.js`. I'm making a XP system with fs. I can do this with `db.add` on module `quick.db`:

```js
const db = require ('quick.db')
const userEXP = db.fetch (`exp_${message.author.id}_${message.guild.id}`)
if (message.length > 7) db.add (userEXP, Math.floor (message.length/3))
```

So, with this code, if the user will type the message and if the message's length will belong from 7, the bot will add `point / 3` to the user's account. How can I do this with fs?

Comment: You're showing code that reads/writes to a database, not the filesystem. Can you explain why you think you need `fs` at all?

Comment: Because, I want to learn `fs` professionally, because I'll start to `Atom` and I'll finish `FogCreek (Glitch)`.

Comment: Okay, but it's literally _just_ the filesystem i/o library, so what do you want to do here? If you want to write files, instead of using a database, then as a fellow engineer that makes no sense: if you _have_ a database, use it. It's so much easier to back up, has a better filesystem footprint, can be distributed, etc. etc. Wanting to learn how to real and write files is fine, but use the right tool for the job: this problem does not need `fs`, and would plain be worse.